# Working out frequency

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, dimensional-analysis

I have the question "If an object moving in a circle has a period of 24 hours, what is its frequency ?"

I know that frequency $= \frac{1}{T}$,  where $T$ is the period.

Therefore,  $f = \frac{1}{24}*60*60$ ( to get it in seconds)

And so the frequency is $150 Hz$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Nope.  Think about your answer for a second.  $150 \textrm{ Hz}$ means that it spins $150$ times **every second**.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @Bye_World, take a Look at the answer.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. You mean your answer?  It looks fine (though I touched up the formatting a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time period is $24 \textrm{ hours}$, it means: $$24\cdot 60\cdot 60 \textrm{ seconds}=86400 \textrm{ seconds}$$

Since you already know that:

$$\textrm{frequency} = 1/\textrm{time period}$$

$$\textrm{frequency}=\frac 1{86400}=1.15740740\times 10^{-5}\textrm{ Hz}$$

Always remember to use the data in appropriate units. If you will use the time period in hours, then you are not going to get frequency in Hertz.

Comment: Thank you. Could I also leave the answer as 1.2 x 10^-5 Hz ?

Comment: It depends on how precise or up to what significant figures the answer is required.